# Swift: Cannot override static method implemented in a framework

Tags: swift

When I call a generic function (`<T : Decodable>`) in a framework, the framework looks up a static method (`T.decode()`) on the type -- and always resolves it to the framework's default implementation of that method. I have provided my own implementation of the same method, but the framework ignores it. This is a problem, because the method is designed to be overridden.

Simplified, it looks like this:

#### Code from the framework (separate module)

```
public protocol Decodable {
    static func decode()
}

// (parameter required in example to make it generic)
public func letsGo<T: Decodable>(_: T) {
    T.decode() // this always calls Castable.decode()
}

// some default implementations:
public protocol Castable : Decodable {}

extension Castable {
    static func decode() {
        print("a default decode implementation for some standard types")
    }
}

extension Bool : Castable {}
// ...etc.
```

#### My code

I override (?) decode for `Bool`:

```
// I import the framework

extension Bool {
    static func decode() {
        print("my specialized decode for Bool")
    }
}


let myBool: Bool = true

letsGo(myBool)
```

Breakpoints confirm I never enter my specialized decode in my real project. Running my example code in a playground will most likely result in the correct method being called, so it's just for illustration purposes.

I haven't found any dispatch rules for static members. Could someone shed some light on that behavior?

Comment: Try making the `extension Bool : Castable {}` conform to `Decodable` directly (or also), instead of (in addition to) `Castable`. I.e., `extension Bool : Decodable {}` (or `extension Bool : Castable, Decodable {}`)

Comment: Yeah, that might do the trick. I considered doing just that but decided against it, because next time I run `pod update` my changes will be gone :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a generic type (in `letsGo(...)`) constrained to `Decodable` to access---in case where the generic is a boolean---the blueprinted `decode()` function, then you should extend `Bool` by conformance to `Decodable` rather than `Castable`.

Also, unless you have some specific reason for it, the default implementation for `decode()` could possibly rather be placed in an extension to `Decodable`; since `decode()` is a function naturally associated with `Decodable` in a stronger sense than with `Castable`. You could also, naturally, in addition to this add a specific `Castable`-default implementation for `decode()`.

Now, you're of course free to extend `Bool` by conformance to `Castable` in addition to `Decodable`, just make sure the include the latter if you want a `Bool`-specific non-default version of `decode()`. E.g.:

```
extension Bool : Decodable, Castable {
     static func decode() {
        print("my specialized decode for Bool")
    }
}
```

Finally note that extensions such as these are "global", so it shouldn't matter if you put this code in 'The framework' or in 'My Code'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Although possible, editing the framework code isn't desirable since the edits will disappear every time the framework is updated. That said, getting rid of `Castable` completely and replacing it with an extension of `Decodable` didn't have any effect on the outcome. Have you found some kind of documentation on why that would lead to different behavior?

Comment: As for where the extensions are located, I agree that it shouldn't matter where I put it. But the buggy history of the Swift compiler has taught me to take nothing for granted. Combine that with a (probably) buggy optimizer and a module boundary and everything's possible. For instance, it might erroneously optimize away dynamic dispatch of `decode()` in the cases where it already knows of an implementation (`Bool` in this case). But I'm just guessing.